# How to get the function result in ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In `ng-repeat` trying to display the location address by passing the latitude and longitude to a function as shown below:

```
$scope.address = function(lat,lng){
    return reverseGeocode.geocodePosition(lat,lng, function(address){
        console.log(address);
        return address;
    });
};
```

I am using `reverseGeocode.geocodePosition` to fetch the address and below is my view

```
<table class="rideTable">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="" ng-repeat="item in rideDetailsArray">
         <td class="ridTd">
            <div class="rideName">Ride {{$index + 1}}</div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>Pick location : {{address(item.pick_lat,item.pick_long)}}</p>
            <p>Drop location : {{address(item.drop_lat,item.drop_long)}}</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Pick location and drop location is not displaying in the view. How can i fix this and can i get any help.

Comment: post the code for reverseGeocode

Comment: I already posted am getting the address generated in console but not updating in view

Comment: Well, `$scope.address` doesn't return anything

Comment: I believe you need to work with promises; use `$q` promise to resolve the data that arrived asynchronously. Initialise it: `var deferred = $q.defer();`, resolve it inside of your *geocode*: `deferred.resolve(address);`, return a promise: `return deferred.promise;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the response as well, Change your function as

```
$scope.address = function(lat,lng){
    return reverseGeocode.geocodePosition(lat,lng, function(address){
        console.log(address);
        return address;
    });
};
```

Comment: does it return the value

Comment: No its not returning

Comment: But am getting the address in console

Comment: @Raghav then your data arrives asynchronously, you need to work with promises, consider looking into [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) AngularJS promises

Answer (score 1):

try this call function from ng-repeat

```
     $scope.LocationNameFilter = function (id)//here pass your object id
{
                if ($scope.GetLocation.length > 0) {
                    var SelectStream = [];
                    if (id) {
                        SelectStream = $filter('filter')($scope.GetLocation, 
                        { _id: id });    //some condition passing your values 
                    }
                    return SelectStream[0].AddressName;
                }
                else {

                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.address` is a function which doesn't return anything. So, by default, the return value is `undefined`.

Thus, AngularJS displays it as blank in the view. You may want to change the function as below:

```
$scope.address = function(lat,lng){
    return reverseGeocode.geocodePosition(lat,lng, function(address){
        console.log(address);
        return address;
    });
};
```

Comment: @Raghav -- Then this question cannot be answered without looking at `reverseGeocode.geocodePosition`. Edit your question and include the details.